# Attaching touch event to single sprite in libGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have several sprites on the screen and I need to register touch events to each of them. I have an input processor registered to the screen, but the sprites will be overlapping and I need to be able to click on the sprite that is on top so do not want to use the sprites position to register the touch events.

is the best option to extend the sprite class and implement InputProcessor? if so how do I extend the sprite class properly?

Comment: Are you using Actor and Stage objects?

Comment: no, just drawing sprites

Comment: It would be better to use `Scene2d`, as it was made for this. Else you need to get all `Sprite`s on your touchpos and store a `priority` or a `z-value` for every `Sprite`, to know which one to choose.

Comment: using scene 2D sounds like the best option. I have never used it before but I am imagining that if i create a stage, and exchange all of my current Sprite objects for Image objects, add them to the stage and then call stage.draw(spriteBatch) instead of drawing each individually, i wont have to change much of my code as they share many of the same methods such as setPosition() etc...     am i correct?

Comment: That should be correct. I have changed all the actors in my game to sprites and it wasn't too much work.